# How to call a PHP class member function from a Java file?

Tags: java, php

I am using PHP/Java bridge to run PHP scripts on the Tomcat server. Can someone point me to an example as to how to call my PHP scripts from a Java file.

```
<?php 

class X{

//variables

//functions   

 }

?>
```

Now I want to call the member functions of class X using its object via a Java file. How do I do this? I want to implement multithreading using the Java file and call multiple PHP functions on separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [JPHP](http://ivoras.sharanet.org/projects/jphp.html) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Found an example here -

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples/source.php?source=PhpThreads.java

Couldn't make out much though