# PHP and Java interoperablity

Tags: java, php

I am working on windows using tomcat 6 and PHP/Java Bridge. I know how to access a Java file from PHP but how do we do it the other way i.e accessing PHP from Java

```
<?php
require_once("java\Java.inc");
$systemInfo = new Java("java.lang.System");
print "Total seconds since January 1, 1970: 
".$systemInfo->currentTimeMillis();
?>
```

Also how do I access Java classes that are created by me. Do I write a CLASSPATH env variable or change the php.ini config file?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727129/how-to-call-a-php-class-member-function-from-a-java-file

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [JPHP](http://ivoras.sharanet.org/projects/jphp.html), which embeds PHP into the Java VM.

Comment: No I want to use PHP/Java Bridge. I cant install JPHP on windows